# How to disable password access from Win7 to XP folder sharing

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, network-shares

I have `2 PC`'s. One is `XP PC` other is `Win7 PC`. Both are in same network and same group. I have a **Shared FOLDER** in XP. I want to access it through the network using `IP` from my Win7 PC. Yes, I can access to the `shared FOLDER` buy using credentials of XP PC.

Here I won't that way. I need to give access without asking password. I mean, when I'm run the `\\XP PC IP\Shared FOLDER\` from my `Win7 PC` it should open the folder without asking credentials. How Can I Do It?

**Updated**

`XP PC IP` = 10.17.255.1

`Win7 IP` = 10.17.1.88

Comment: Hi, If the IP of your both machines are in same series, for example 172.16.x.x then in that case it will not prompt for asking credentials while accessing the other machine drive through UNC path.

Comment: @vembutech Thanks, I have update my question.